# AWS Lambda Python 3 check event variable exists

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

```
 try: 
        event['ids']
 except NameError: 
        ids = None
```

This is throwing a KeyError. I just want to check if the event variable exists and set to none or pass the value if it does. 
I have also tried to use

```
if (len(event['ids']) < 1)
```

but get an error. 
Am I missing something?  I may or may not have all my event keys passed and want to check for existence.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use the `get` method. The second parameter is the default value if the key doesn't exist in the dictionary. It's the standard way to get values from a dictionary when you're not sure if the key exists and you don't want an exception.

```
ids = event.get('ids', None)
```

Comment: For certain data... such as `OrderItems` in Amazons SP-API, you can't apply the 'data.get()` function for keys because it's a list of dictionaries. Getting `main_data = res.get_order_items()` initial payload, then using `ord_items = main_data.get('OrderItems')` to get correct data... but trying to use `ord_items.get('ASIN','')` does not work "list has no attribute get()". Is there a way around this? As this is the easiest way to check if a key exists. I've been having to use `main_data['OrderItems'][0]['ASIN']`.

Answer (score -2):

We can check if the key 'key1' exists in the Json dictionary.

```
{ 
"key1":"value1"
}
```

To retrieve the value 'value1' if the key 'key1' exists in the dictionary.

```
if event.get('key1',None) != None:
   value = event.get('key1',None)
```

Comment: Technically it does, but it's not the most elegant solution.